# get post from facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I want to get the posts from my facebook page using Javascript SDK and Graph API.

However, once I logged in, the posts showed on the console log is all undefined. (I have 16 consoles)
The name I get is correct, anyone has some ideas?

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
   } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      FB.login();
   } else {
      FB.login();
   }
});

function testAPI() {
   FB.api('/me', function(response){
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
   });
   FB.api('/me/feed', function(response){
      console.log(i + " : " + response.data.length);
      for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
          console.log(i + " : " + response.data[i].message);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Have you granted the permission read_feed for your app?

Comment: Just log the whole `response` object to the console – then you can inspect its structure there.

Answer (score 0):

Not every response may have a `message`. But since you are getting 16 messages in the console that means the API is giving you the correct result. Now its on you how you want to use the result. You can check the detailed result with-

```
console.log(i + " : " + response.data[i]);
```